# How to change the text orientation of stacked bar chart created with Plotly Express?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-express

I am completely new to data visualisation with Plotly.
I've created a stacked bar chart with text labels,
but the single-digit value have rotated automatically.
How can I make all texts shown without being rotated?

```py
fig = px.bar(
    data_stack,
    y = "newform",
    x = "percentage",
    color = "Qcat",
    barmode = "stack",
    text = "size",
    orientation = "h")
```

Here's a screenshot for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
fig.update_traces(textangle=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but what I want to manipulate is the orientation of the values INSIDE the blue stacked bar.. Any ideas? :P

Comment: Sorry for that, try this: fig.update_traces(textangle=0)

Comment: works like magic! thanksssss

Comment: by the way @tzinie where can i see the documentation of all the parameters for the function .update_traces please?

Comment: you can checkout this one https://plotly.com/python/reference/#bar-textangle